# How to fix "gravity issue in unity AR project"

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Project: Augmented game (vuforia)

I have a plane over which a ball resides.

The plane has rigid body and mesh collider on it.
The ball has a sphere collider and rigid body on it with gravity turned on.

As i play the game,the ball falls through the plane and keeps on falling.

I want the ball to stay on the plane so that i can control it with touch input.

Comment: Did you add a `physicmaterial` to your collider?

Comment: yes i have, both the plane and ball has materials on them

Comment: The collider you have on your ball also has a spot for a [physicmaterial](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) which is different than your normal material you add, i think you might be missing that one.

Comment: the physicalmaterail is in place but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solved using the I `TrackableEventHandler`.

Look at this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia; 

public class MarkerController: MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehavior;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehavior = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>(); 
        if (mTrackableBehavior)
        {
            mTrackableBehavior.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this); 
        }

    }

    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if(newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            OnTrackingFound(); 
        } else
        {
            OnTrackingLost(); 
        }
    }

    private void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

        Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(); 


        for (int i = 0; i < this.transform.GetChildCount(); i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("Activating the children");
            this.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(true); 
        }

        foreach(Renderer component in rendererComponents)
        {
            component.enabled = true; 
        }

        foreach(Collider component in colliderComponents)
        {
            component.enabled = true; 
        }

        Debug.Log("Tracking of " + mTrackableBehavior.TrackableName + " found"); 
    }

    private void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

        Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>();


        for (int i = 0; i < this.transform.GetChildCount(); i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("Deactivating children");
            this.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
        {
            component.enabled = false;
        }

        foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
        {
            component.enabled = false;
        }

        Debug.Log("Tracking of " + mTrackableBehavior.TrackableName + " lost");

    }
}
```

In this class, I've only activated the components when the tracking of the markers is found! Otherwise it will be deactivated, and when the tracking is found again, then it will be displayed as the way it was before losing track.

I've added this script to the ARCamera component. Works fine here!